# How to process onchange events for select elements which is dynamically created using javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I have to create a few "select" elements in a html file dynamically.
And I also intend to create the same amount "select" elements according to the value of
the former created "select" elements.

Thus I will have a set of "select" elements pair. 
When the first "select" element's selected value is changed,
the second "select" elements will refresh its options using the according records in a database.

My problem is I can't receive the correct value of the first "select" element.
Everytime when the onchange event is called, the value passed on to onchange function( in my case, it's called "fillSource()" is the value before the change happened instead of the changed selected value.

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

The following is my javascript code:

```
<script>

    var selectCount = 1;
    var cats = #{dropCatsJson};
    var subcats = #{dropSourceJson};
    function addNewSource() {

        var inputchange = document.createElement('select');
        inputchange.options[0] = new Option("pls Select", "0");
        inputchange.id="schange";

        var input1 = document.createElement('select');
        for( var i=0;i< cats.length;i++ ) {
            var s = cats[i];                        
            input1.options.add( new Option(s.Name, s.Id) );            
        }

        input1.id = 's' + selectCount;

        //input1.onchange = new Function("alert(\"input1 changed\")");       
        input1.onchange = new Function("fillSource(" + input1.value + ")");

        document.getElementById('newSource').appendChild(input1);
        document.getElementById('newSource').appendChild(inputchange);
        selectCount = selectCount + 1;
    } 

    function fillSource(input1)
    {

        var dropsub = document.getElementById("schange");
        dropsub.options.length = 0;//clear all the options.
        for( var i=0;i< subcats.length;i++ ) {
            var s = subcats[i];
            if( s.ParentId == input1.value ) 
            {               
                dropsub.options.add( new Option(s.Name, s.Id) );
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

===============================================================================
final code that works. 
Please notice that you should add onchange event for newly created
select elements like this:

```
input1.onchange = function(){fillsource(input1.value)};
```

here is my test.html code:

```
<html> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var selectCount = 1;
function addNewSearch() 
{ 
     //alert("add");
     var input1 = document.createElement('select');
     input1.options[0] = new Option("s1","1");
     input1.options[1] = new Option("s2","2");
     input1.name = 's' + selectCount;
     input1.id = 's' + selectCount;
     input1.onchange = function(){fillsource(input1.value)};
     document.body.appendChild(input1);

     selectCount = selectCount +1;
     //alert(selectCount);
     var selcount = document.getElementById('selCount');
     selcount.textContent = selectCount;
} 

function fillsource(ivalue)
{
     alert(ivalue);
} 

</script> 

<form name= "Search" id= "SearchForm"  method= "post"> 

<select name= "SearchWhat" onchange = "setSearchField()"> 
<option value = "both"> Both Event and Task </option> 
<option value = "event"> Event </option> 
<option value = "task" > Task </option> 
</select> 

<label id="selCount"></label>

<input type="submit" value= "submit" name = "btn_submit"/> 
<input type="button" name= "newsearch" value= "New Search" onClick= "addNewSearch()"> 
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide some test data for dropCatsJson and dropSourceJson?

Comment: @Barmar has solved my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're capturing the value at the time you create the `select` element, and hard-coding it into the `onchange` function. You need to use a closure:

```
input1.onchange = (function(input1) {fillsource(input1.value)})(input1);
```

Comment: Your answer inspires me that there's anthor way to solve this problem. first, I pass the id attribute of the first select elements; then I caputer the value in my function fillsource() by using document.getElementById(), and in the end when I use input1.value, it works.     `code` input1.onchange = new Function("fillSource(\"s1\")");   var inputselect = document.getElementById(input1); `code`

Comment: You could do that, but why call `getElementById()` when you don't need to?

Comment: thanks for your advice. I changed to `input1.onchange = function() {fillsource(input1.value)};`

Comment: That should work as well. I was mistakenly thinking that `input1` was a for-loop variable, in which case another level of closure would be necessary.